# Sesquilinear Forms: Polarization

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

*This thread is only Q&A.**

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider the transforms:
$$q[\varphi]:=s(\varphi,\varphi)\quad s(\varphi,\psi):=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{\alpha=0\ldots3}i^\alpha q[\varphi+i^\alpha\psi]$$

> Then they are inverses:
>   $$s\mapsto q\mapsto s\quad q\mapsto s\mapsto q$$

How can I check this?

**See the guidelines: [Q&A](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)*

Comment: If you assume $q$ came from a sesquilinear form $s$, then you can recover $s$. But if you start with a quadratic form, you don't necessarily get a sesquilinear from $s(\varphi,\psi)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{3}i^{k}q(\varphi+i^{k}\psi)$. You need to be clear about your assumptions.

Comment: @TrialAndError: Yes, it was actually you who teached me the problematic. :)) But the transformations work in any case! *(Though the result won't necessarily be sesquilinear.)*

Comment: @TrialAndError: So due to the above one could in some sense say there are more quadratic forms than sesquilinear ones.

Comment: If you start with a quadratic form $q$ you'll get an additive form $s$. And if you start with an additive form $s$, then you'll get a quadratic form. Quadratic $q(x+y)+q(x-y)=2q(x)+2q(y)$ and $q(ix)=q(x)$ gives $s$ with $s(x+x',y)=s(x,y)+s(x',y)$, $s(x,y+y')=s(x,y)+s(x,y')$ $s(ix,y)=is(x,y)=s(x,-iy)$. I think those should be in one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: @TrialAndError: Ah yes they seem in 1-1 correspondence. *(Good point!!)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that it is:
$$4=|1+1|^2\quad2=|1\pm i|^2\quad0=|1-1|^2$$

Thus calculation gives:
$$q[\varphi]=\frac{1}{4}\sum_\alpha i^\alpha q[\varphi+i^\alpha\varphi]=\frac{1}{4}\{4q[\varphi]+2iq[\varphi]-0q[\varphi]-2iq[\varphi]\}=q[\varphi]$$

Note that it is:
$$4=\sum_\alpha1^\alpha\quad0=\sum_\alpha i^\alpha,\sum_\alpha(-1)^\alpha$$

Thus calculation gives:
$$s(\varphi,\psi)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_\alpha i^\alpha s(\varphi+i^\alpha\psi,\varphi+i^\alpha\psi)=\frac{1}{4}\left\{0+4s(\varphi,\psi)+0+0\right\}=s(\varphi,\psi)$$

Concluding the assertion.